# Access Denied while logging in via SSH (PuTTY)

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04, putty

I'm having trouble logging in to my server via ssh (PuTTY) on a new username that I created.

During the initial installation of the server, I set up a username of "admin". While logged in as "admin" I ran the following command: `sudo useradd tempuser`, then entered the password for the new username.

From my Windows box, I connect to the server and enter the new username, "tempuser", and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now it asks for the password. I've entered it successfully a couple of times and I receive the error `Access denied` each time.

Do I have to add this new user somewhere else in order to log in via SSH?

Comment: Depends on your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  If you have the option `AllowUsers` defined, you'd need it there for sure. [sshd manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config+5)

Comment: Thank you...you sparked something there. I remember editing the sshd_config for something, its been awhile. I'll take a look, thanks again!

Comment: Yep sure enough, tempuser was not defined in the `AllowUsers` entry. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear it, good learning experience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add `tempuser` to your `sshd_config` file.

To do so at a prompt:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Look for a line that, by default, reads: `#AllowUsers`; you want to change it to (or add it, if it doesn't exist, as) `AllowUsers tempuser`

Save the file - in `nano` it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (that's the capital letter "o") then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to quit, then type `sudo service sshd restart` to load the new config.